# Java: Detecting open PowerPoint file & determining its path

Tags: java, file, powerpoint, detection

I've been researching this for some hours now, but to no avail. The most promising library seems to be [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html), but I'm not quite sure (from reading its documents) that it can perform the simple task of **detecting open instances of PowerPoint and determining their path**.

I used to accomplish this chore in Visual Basic (yes, I know it's dreadful) by the use of this line:

```
Set PPTXApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POI can manipulate various Microsoft Office type documents, it's not made to manipulate running apps via COM, which is what you were doing in VB.

COM interaction isn't something that's built into Java, but there are third party libraries like [Jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) or [COM4J](http://com4j.java.net/) that may help you.

Another SO post that may be interesting for you can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947661/any-method-for-accessing-windows-com-methods-using-java)